# Xamarin - Pressing "Add NuGet Packages..." does nothing

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, html-agility-pack

Trying to add a NuGet package - "Html Agility Pack" to be specific.

But.. Clicking Add NuGet Package doesn't do anything.

Nothing happens when you right-click on the project icon and go to Add > Add NuGet Package.

And under Project > Add NuGet Package... nothing happens also.

Running Mac OS X 10.11.5

Question that is the same as mine but no answer in it. Feel mine is more detailed.

[Add NuGet Packages on Xamarin Studio for Mac Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513091/add-nuget-packages-not-working)

**EDIT:**

I reinstalled Xamarin but nothing happened. + no longer need the HTML agility pack. Now I need the  Microsoft HTTP CLient Libraries pack and the Json.net pack

**Link to Log:** [NuGet Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66vfwSXdArkU05wMHZ0WGhiQjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I believe it is a bug in Xamarin Studio 6.0. However without seeing the contents of your IDE log (Help - Open Log Directory) then this is just a guess.

Comment: As @MattWard mentioned, the IDE logs might be helpful. Also, do you see any error messages in the package console when you try to add the package?
 
"View -> Pads -> Package Console"

Comment: I looked at all the logs. Just Ctrl + F > NuGet but I didn't find anything? @Kent.Green

Comment: I looked at all the logs. Just Ctrl + F > NuGet but I didn't find anything? @MattWard

Comment: This is what happened when i press Add NuGet Package. [link to document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66vfwSXdArkU05wMHZ0WGhiQjQ/view?usp=sharing) @MattWard

Comment: Thanks from that log file I can see that this is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38048) that has been reported. It is fixed in Xamarin Studio 6.1.

Comment: Is there a way of me getting 6.1 I only have 6.0.1 but all is up to date... @MattWard **EDIT** I'm installing 6.1 from the alpha channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going into Alpha Channels in the updates page then switching to the alpha channel, updating xamarin to 6.1 fixes the bug.